# Wordpress: numeric slug for product name returns 404

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce installed on my web-site. I need product slug to be numeric

e.g. /catalog/zapasnye-chasti-k-oborudovaniyu/zakleivayuschie-gruppy/1024/

but it returns 404 page. I tried to set product permalink to `/catalog/%product_cat%/%postname%/` and add this to functions.php:

```
function escape_my_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ){
    $permalink = str_replace('%postname%/', '', $permalink);

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'escape_my_permalink', 99 );
```

worked perfectly fine for numeric links but it made products that are placed under 1st level category return 404 page

e.g. /catalog/vakuumnoe-oborudovanie/vakuumnyy_upakovshchik_a2vac5002/

while products in subcategories worked fine

e.g. /catalog/etiketirovochnoe-oborudovanie/oborudovanie-a2/a2-l120-slim_1/

I know why it works so, but I can't find the solution to this. This error is pretty popular but I couldn't find any actual solution. All I need is to make numeric slug in products show the required page. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
   function do_rewrite(){
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->rewritereplace[16] = '(.+)';
        add_rewrite_tag('%product%', '(.+)');
        $post_type = 'product';
        add_rewrite_tag( "%product_num%", '(.+)', "post_type=$post_type&product=" );
        $permastruct = "catalog/(.+)/%product_num%"; //for permalink structure: /catalog/%product_cat%/

        $args = array(
            'with_front'  => true,
            'paged'       => true,
            'ep_mask'     => EP_NONE,
            'feed'        => false,
            'forcomments' => false,
            'walk_dirs'   => true,
            'endpoints'   => false,
        );

        add_permastruct( $post_type, $permastruct, $args );
        flush_rewrite_rules();//comment this after first run

    }
    add_action('init', 'do_rewrite',1,0);
```